# Обработка строк из excel и многопоточность

Tags: python, многопоточность, строки

Требуется взять из excel таблицы строки (порядка 500000), убрать из них все лишнее и подготовить для обработки в VW.

Задачу выполнить удалось, однако, код выполняется довольно долго (не сильно нагружая при этом систему). Хочу существенно ускорить его выполнение и понять, почему нагрузка на систему низкая.

Я попробовал использовать библиотеку multiprocessing, но существенных изменений во времени работы (а так же в нагрузке на систему) не произошло (это ведь связано с GIL, потому что код не использует сторонних библиотек ?).
Как я вижу решение проблемы: использовать для всех работ со строками библиотеку на С.

В общении с pyhton новичок. Код может быть максимально не правильным, но он работает :)

Пожалуйста, помогите оптимизировать программу (изменить код, помочь с поиском библиотеки).

Задачу решил так:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
import multiprocessing as mp

def to_vw_format(document, label=None):
    stemmer = SnowballStemmer('russian')
    reg = re.compile('[^а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9- ]')
    if type(document) == int:
        document = str(document)
    document = reg.sub(' ', document)
    words = []
    for w in document.split():
        if len(w) > 1:
            words.append(stemmer.stem(w))
    stmstr = ' '.join(words)
    return str(label or '') + ' |text ' + stmstr + '\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aa = 3
    df=pd.read_excel(r'123.xlsx', header=None)
    names = [df[0][i] for i in range(df.shape[0]//2)]
    names1 = [df[0][i] for i in range(df.shape[0]//2, df.shape[0])]
    labels = [df[2][i] for i in range(df.shape[0]//2)]
    labels1 = [df[2][i] for i in range(df.shape[0]//2, df.shape[0])]
    if len(names) != len(names1):
        names.append('')
        labels.append('')

    train_data = [] 

    with mp.Pool(aa) as pool:
        for i in range(len(names)):
            for result in pool.starmap(to_vw_format, [(names[i], labels[i]), (names1[i], labels1[i])]):
                train_data.append(result)
```

Comment: Вызываю в цикле, через pool.starmap(to_vw_format, [(names[i], labels[i]), (names1[i], labels1[i])])

Comment: Прошу прощения, сейчас досконально перепроверил все скобки - все на месте. Код копировался с файла, который запускается и работает. Не могли бы Вы точно указать спорный момент ?

Comment: А, пардон. Все нормально.

Comment: Разобрался, почему код не нагружается систему. Вся проблема в том, что я даю информацию для обработки по одному элементу из 2-х списков. Если объединить 4 списка в один (сгруппировав их по 2 элемента) и убрать цикл вовсе, получается практически трехкратное сокращение времени работы на моей машине и процессор нагружается максимально.